# Why few hours automatically getting added to date while fetching utc date from postgress with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, date, utc

We have UTC date stored in postgress, I have a requirement where I need to show that date in server's time zone. For that I did changes as below:

selectedAttempt is an object which hold all the data stored in postgress.

```
var assignmentDate = (selectedAttempt?.DateCreatedUtc) ?? DateTime.MinValue;
var dateinServerTimezone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(assignmentDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local).ToString(dateFormate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But when I see `selectedAttempt?.DateCreatedUtc` it is already different than date stored in postgress, I am not able to understand why is it so?

My Timezone: India Standard Time

**utc date stored in postgress:** "2023-01-30 17:54:15.13-06"

**What I see in c# :** {30-01-2023 23:54:15}

Comment: "UTC date stored in Postgress" - that says -06, so it's not UTC. The value you're getting in C# is the UTC equivalent of that datetime.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama -06 is which format then? while storing date we are storing utc time only. And why few hours added to date in C#?

Comment: "And why few hours added to date in C#" - no hours are being added.

Comment: _"-06 is which format then?"_ - I'm not sure, but it's clear that this stands for the timezone UTC-6 (as in 6 hours behind UTC). And indeed, 17 + 6 = 23.

Comment: Nitpicking, it's the offset, not the timezone, which is often used interchangeably. You are actually storing local time. UTC is defined as Zero Offset without Daylight savings. So if you have a time with -6 hours offset in the db, then it's not utc.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Postgress shows time 17:54:15.13-06 and c# showing 23:54:15 so hours are added here

Comment: 17 -6 is the same instant as 23 +0 ... That's why ProgrammingLlama is referring to "no hours added"

Comment: Hours are not added. For the love of all that is good in the world, both dates reference the same instant in time (well, the C# one seems to be absent the milliseconds but I expect that's a formatting issue). Like, I can say the time now is almost 5 PM, but if you're in India, you probably think that it's almost 1:30 PM. We are both talking about the same instant in time, but the offset (sorry for my past transgressions, Fildor) is different. You are in UTC+0530, and I'm in UTC+0900. You have saved a local time (not UTC time) to your database.

Comment: You are requesting that time back in C# as UTC time (i.e. offset from 0), so it is therefore adjusting the offset to 0, which involves adding the opposite number of hours and minutes to the time. It is not changing the actual time relative to the world we live in, just how the same instant is represented.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama _"sorry for my past transgressions"_ - haha :D Yeah I am nitpicky about that because I just spent several hours explaining an issue we had to a manager that was exactly based on that very distinction.

Comment: IMHO If you are working with timezones, just use `DateTimeOffset` everywhere. `DateTime` methods for adjusting between timezones are almost unusable.

Answer (score 0):

The difference you are observing is due to the time zone conversion that occurs when retrieving the date from PostgreSQL in C#. The date itself remains the same, but the representation changes based on the time zone conversion.
To display the date in the server's time zone, you can try to use the **TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc** method, as you have done in your code. This will convert the UTC date to the desired time zone. In your case, you are using **TimeZoneInfo.Local**, which represents the local time zone of the server where the code is running. The resulting dateinServerTimezone will be in the server's time zone.
If you want to display the original UTC date as it is, without any time zone conversion, you can use the **DateTime.ToUniversalTime** method.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question because OP's question is based on the assumption that they have written a UTC datetime to the database and are confused about why it is no longer UTC. The problem actually lies in the code to write the datetime in the first place, which hasn't been provided.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama  I am also new to how we are storing date, as per code We are reading kafka message this message has utc date, then ef help us to save kafka message to postgress including utcdate value. But I see this kafka message is have wrong utc, I mean if my system publish some utc date consumer code receives with +5 hours in utc date. this is confusing for me as well